How to create a VisualTransformation with the format "CR XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" including a length as a parameter
I am making this visual transformation, however I can't get it to work properly:
class InputAccountMaskTransformation(private val len: Int = 20) : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        val transformed = buildAnnotatedString {
            append("CR ")
            append(
                insertStringFromEnd(
                    text.text,
                    4,
                    " ",
                    stringMaxLength = len,
                    fillEmptyWith = "-",
                )
            )
        }

        return TransformedText(
            text = transformed,
            offsetMapping = object : OffsetMapping {
                override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
                    val transformedSplit = transformed.split(" ")
                    var increment = 2 + (transformedSplit.count() - 1)
                    if (text.text.isNotBlank()) {
                        transformedSplit.forEach { if (it.contains("----")) increment-- }
                    }
                    return offset.plus(increment)
                }

                override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
                    var decrement = 2
                    if (text.text.isNotBlank()) {
                        for (c in transformed) {
                            if (c == '-' || c == ' ') {
                                decrement++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    val transform = offset.minus(decrement)
                    val offsetValue = if (transform > 0 && transform < transformed.count()) {
                        transform
                    } else {
                        if (transform > (transformed.count() / 2)) {
                            transformed.count()
                        } else {
                            0
                        }
                    }
                    return offsetValue
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

This has a correct behavior when manually entering:

When I try to edit the first digits, the offset is not correct:


Please show the inputs and outputs and errors as text, not as images. There are many reasons. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

these images are not errors, they are a gif of the textfield's behavior

The problem is that they are images. Please read the post I provided earlier. If it is important that images ar shown, then describe them so we do not need to view them.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
